# Apache Camel : Corba Endpoint Message Error

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, corba

Am calling a corba server using a cxf client.

CXF client is successfully receiving the response if its a primitive type, but when the server is sending objects, it fails with below error

```
The JDK version is : jdk1.7.0_55
CXf version : 2.6.0
ESB Server : Jboss Fuse 6.0.0
```

Error log says:

```
10:51:30,208 | WARN  | eadpool; w: Idle | PhaseInterceptorChain            | 150 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-api - 2.6.0.redhat-60024 | Interceptor for {http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/corba/idl/subsProfileProv}balancemanagement.SubscriberProfileProvisionCORBAService#{http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/corba/idl/subsProfileProv}createSubscriberProfile has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaBindingException: org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaBindingException: Error reading streamable value
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaConduit.close(CorbaConduit.java:145)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)[150:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)[150:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)[150:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:456)[150:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:112)[197:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.fabric.FabricTraceProcessor.process(FabricTraceProcessor.java:81)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:334)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.StreamCachingInterceptor.process(StreamCachingInterceptor.java:52)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:308)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86)[133:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.syncInvoke(CxfConsumer.java:133)[197:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.invoke(CxfConsumer.java:75)[197:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.10.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)[150:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_55]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_55]
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)[150:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)[150:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)[150:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)[150:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.runtime.CorbaDSIServant.invoke(CorbaDSIServant.java:175)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:642)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:205)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1700)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1558)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:940)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:198)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:712)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.dispatch(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:469)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1230)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:490)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:519)[:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaBindingException: Error reading streamable value
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.runtime.CorbaStreamableImpl._read(CorbaStreamableImpl.java:51)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.utils.FixedAnyImpl.read_value(FixedAnyImpl.java:55)[:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.RequestImpl.unmarshalReply(RequestImpl.java:352)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleDIIReply(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:476)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.processResponse(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:668)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:373)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:147)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.RequestImpl.doInvocation(RequestImpl.java:325)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.RequestImpl.invoke(RequestImpl.java:246)[:1.7.0_55]
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaConduit.buildRequest(CorbaConduit.java:194)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaConduit.close(CorbaConduit.java:141)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:236)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.ByteBufferWithInfo.position(ByteBufferWithInfo.java:176)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_2.alignAndCheck(CDRInputStream_1_2.java:95)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_long(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:494)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readStringOrIndirection(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:553)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_string(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:589)[:1.7.0_55]
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_string(CDRInputStream.java:175)[:1.7.0_55]
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.runtime.CorbaObjectReader.readString(CorbaObjectReader.java:279)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.runtime.CorbaObjectReader.read(CorbaObjectReader.java:111)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.runtime.CorbaObjectReader.readStruct(CorbaObjectReader.java:318)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.runtime.CorbaObjectReader.read(CorbaObjectReader.java:128)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.runtime.CorbaObjectReader.readStruct(CorbaObjectReader.java:318)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.runtime.CorbaObjectReader.read(CorbaObjectReader.java:128)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
at org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.runtime.CorbaStreamableImpl._read(CorbaStreamableImpl.java:49)[171:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-corba:2.6.0.redhat-60024]
... 77 more
10:51:30,208 | ERROR | eadpool; w: Idle | DefaultErrorHandler              | 133 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.0.redhat-60024 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-M-D4S6T72-55807-1454903203683-5-6 on ExchangeId: ID-M-D4S6T72-55807-1454903203683-5-5). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaBindingException: org.apache.cxf.binding.corba.CorbaBindingException: Error reading streamable value
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5254 - the problem with struct containing sequence of strings.